# Crushed tomatoes - sub with diced or whole?

Tags: substitutions, tomatoes

I have a [barbecue sauce recipe](http://simplyrecipes.com/recipes/dr_pepper_barbecue_sauce/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+elise%2Fsimplyrecipes+%28Simply+Recipes%29) that calls for 1 can of crushed tomatoes. I have cans of whole & cans of diced. Could I just run one of those through the food processor and deem it "crushed"?

EDIT: I also have a few pounds of fresh Roma tomatoes.

Comment: When cooking magazines compare tinned tomato products they often conclude that flavor wise one should buy whole and dice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drain some of the liquid off either of those, whiz it in the food processor, add liquid back as needed to reach the "crushed" consistency.

Comment: Just as an aside, whole canned tomatoes tend to be better quality than crushed. The best tomatoes are canned whole because appearances count. The worst go into crushed tomatoes because how would you ever know?

Answer (score 4):

Even easier and less messy than putting canned whole tomatoes in the food processor is to put them in a stainless or glass bowl that has gently sloping sides.  Use a pizza cutter to roll back and forth, side to side until tomatoes are of the "diced" or "crushed" texture that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two options use the canned whole tomato, not only for the reason that Jenn mentioned (that they will tend to be of higher quality) but also because canned diced tomatoes are usually treated with calcium chloride to help maintain the shape of the dice. That obviously would work against the purpose of crushing them.

Answer (score 1):

I find a pyrex bowl and a potato masher works well when I only have whole tomatoes and need to crush them up.